# Oracle Sql query for ordered output of hierarchical data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table temp_table with multiple columns like person_id and manager_id, person_name, manager_name.

I have to insert or update person records based this table to a person table but i have to select those records with hierarchy.

If the data is like (For the 3rd record manager already exists in the table):

```
PerId PerName MgrId  MgrName
65202 Test1    65201 Test
65203 Test2    65202 Test1
65201 Test     64523 AlreadyPre
```

I have to write a query which returns the 3rd record first then the 1st record and then 2nd record.

I tried writing a self join to select such records where person id = manager id in my temp table and insert those but not able to get the ordering right.

Comment: Show us your expeced results please, maybe all you need is order by. But also please explain what do you mean when you say: I have to insert or update person records based this table. Maybe you can show us the person table and what do you expect that table to look like after update

Comment: Sorry, was not able to check as i was on the way to home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   temp_table
START WITH mgrName = 'AlreadyPre'
CONNECT BY PRIOR PerId = MgrId
ORDER SIBLINGS BY PerName
```

So, for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE temp_table (PerId, PerName, MgrId, MgrName) AS
SELECT 65202, 'Test1', 65201, 'Test' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 65203, 'Test2', 65202, 'Test1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 65201, 'Test',  64523, 'AlreadyPre' FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> PERID | PERNAME | MGRID | MGRNAME   
> ----: | :------ | ----: | :---------
> 65201 | Test    | 64523 | AlreadyPre
> 65202 | Test1   | 65201 | Test      
> 65203 | Test2   | 65202 | Test1
> ```

---

or, if you don't want to hard-code the starting row then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   temp_table
START WITH mgrId NOT IN ( SELECT PerId FROM temp_table )
CONNECT BY PRIOR PerId = MgrId
ORDER SIBLINGS BY PerName
```

Outputs the same as above.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=221aaaefe84f0c2640098ebdab0932fd)*